# How to set up explicit value constructor with linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, explicit-constructor

For a project, im trying to set up a linked list object so that it can be initialized with an explicit value constructor.  I want it to look like this:

```
WORD you("you");//where the object you's linked list now contains y o u;
```

but when I print out the object you, all i see is this symbol "="
and when I print out the length of you, I get -858993459

Here is my explicit value constructor, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
WORD::WORD(string s)
{
front = 0;
int i = 0;
int len = s.length();

if(front == 0)
{   
    front = new alpha_numeric;
    alpha_numeric *p = front;

    while(s[i] <= len)
    {
        p -> symbol = s[i];
        p -> next = new alpha_numeric;
        p = p -> next;
        p -> symbol = s[i++];
    }
    p -> next = 0;
}
}
```

Here is the class declaration file if it helps

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#pragma once

class alpha_numeric //node
{
public:
char symbol; //data in node
alpha_numeric *next;//points to next node
};

class WORD
{
public:
WORD(); //front of list initially set to Null
WORD(const WORD& other);
WORD(string s); //***EXPLICIT VALUE CONSTRUCTOR
bool IsEmpty(); //done
int Length();
void Add(char); //done
//void Insert(WORD bword, int position);
//void operator=(char *s);

friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const WORD& w);//done

private:
alpha_numeric *front; //points to the front node of a list
int length;
};
```

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is `conversion constructor`. An explicit constructor has the `explicit` keyword, and can't make implicit conversions, as yours can.

Comment: I'd start with getting rid of `using namespace std;` from your headers. Same with `#include <iostream>`, you don't need it to be included when class is being declared - move it to .cpp where you work with streams.

Comment: Also `front = 0;` and `if(front == 0)` right after. What for?

Comment: Why would you not just delegate to your own `Add()` method?  DRY.

Comment: @LihO true, I guess ill change that

Comment: @cdhowie I have my own Add method, but the the project requires to to implement this constructor

Comment: Right. Why can't you call `Add()` from the constructor itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set length, so that's why it's garbage. As luthien256 ahd LihO pointed out, your while loop is also wrong, and the if (front == 0) test makes no sense.

Finally, the `p -> symbol = s[i++];` is not needed. Just increment i.

Try this:

```
class alpha_numeric //node
{
public:
char symbol; //data in node
alpha_numeric *next;//points to next node
};

class WORD
{
public:
WORD(); //front of list initially set to Null
WORD(const WORD& other);
WORD(string s); //***EXPLICIT VALUE CONSTRUCTOR
bool IsEmpty(); //done
int Length() { return length; }
alpha_numeric *Front() { return front; }
void Add(char); //done
//void Insert(WORD bword, int position);
//void operator=(char *s);

friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const WORD& w);//done

private:
alpha_numeric *front; //points to the front node of a list
int length;
};

WORD::WORD(string s)
{
  front = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int len = s.length();
  length = len;
  if (length == 0) {
    front = NULL;
    return;
  }
  front = new alpha_numeric;
  alpha_numeric *p = front;

  while(i < len)
  {
      p -> symbol = s[i];
      if (i != len - 1) {
        p -> next = new alpha_numeric;
        p = p -> next;
      }
      else
        p -> next = NULL;
      ++i;
  }
}


int main() {
  WORD you("you");
  alpha_numeric* front = you.Front();
  while(front != NULL) {
    cout<<(front->symbol)<<endl;
    front = front->next;
  }
  cout<<you.Length()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MikeGordon Looks fine to me. Maybe there's a bug in your printing function?

Comment: @Mike Gorden - That doesn't happen when I run it. I included entire code above, along with sample main() method. It prints y o u and then 3 for the length.

Comment: @Mike Gorden - Also, I added a test for empty string, so if you pass in "" then it's handled.

Answer (score 1):

You have `std::string s` and `int i` initialized to `0`. Then you have `int len` initialized to `s.length();` and you want to iterate through this string:

```
while(s[i] <= len) <----------------- THIS IS WRONG
{
    ...
    p -> symbol = s[i++];
}
```

Also note, that complexity of [`std::basic_string::length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/length) is O(1). There is no point of using temporary variable `len`. You are also doing a lot of redundant things like assigning `0` to `front` and then checking `if (front == 0)`. It could look like this:

```
WORD::WORD(std::string s)
{
    length = s.length();
    if (length == 0)
    {
        front = NULL
        return;
    }

    front = new alpha_numeric;
    alpha_numeric *p = front;

    int i = 0;
    while(i < length - 1)
    {
        p->symbol = s[i++];
        p->next = new alpha_numeric;
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->symbol = s[i];
    p->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to delete that last alpha_numeric before throwing away the reference if you decide to go with this one.

Comment: This works, the only thing now is, its coming up with y o u u, instead of y o u.  Do you know why this extra character is being added?

Comment: @nw.: Thanks for pointing out the memory leak. Check my answer now.

Comment: @MikeGordon: I've updated my answer. I have a question for you though: Are you sure that no one will try to call `WORD("")` ?

Comment: @LihO Ok I see, and no, im not sure that no one will try that.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely your while loop is executing.  I believe:

`while(s[i] <= len)`

should be

`while(i < len)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WORD::WORD(string s)
{
  int i;
  int len = s.length();

  front = new alpha_numeric;
  alpha_numeric *p = front;

  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
        p -> symbol = s[i];
        p -> next = (i == len - 1) ? 0 : new alpha_numeric;
        p = p -> next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, assigning `0` to `p->next` is better to leave after loop. In your code evaluation of condition `i == len - 1` is redundant.

Comment: It's better not allocate a next at all if you don't need it.